# Removing quotes from selector names when generating styles with Less mixin

Tags: css, less

I'm working on a legacy project that uses an old version of Less, and moving off it isn't an option anytime soon. I'm refactoring some repetitive theming and I've been trying to use Less mixins to help, but I'm a little stuck, and Less isn't something I've used to any great extent.

I've defined the following themes and mixin:

```
@theme-green: #91ab7a;
@theme-green-text: #fff;
@theme-yellow: #efdf91;
@theme-yellow-text: #00395d;
@theme-red: #722d3d;
@theme-red-text: #fff;
@theme-brown: #a9a196;
@theme-brown-text: #fff;
@theme-grey: #f3f3f3;
@theme-grey-text: #00395d;
@theme-darkBlue: #00395d;
@theme-darkBlue-text: #fff;
@theme-default: @theme-darkBlue;
@theme-default-text: @theme-darkBlue-text;
@theme-navyBlue: #007db5;
@theme-navyBlue-text: #fff;
@theme-cyan: #00adee;
@theme-cyan-text: #fff;
@theme-lightBlue: #b1e7ff;
@theme-lightBlue-text: #00395d;
@themes: 'green' 'yellow' 'red' 'brown' 'grey' 'darkBlue' 'navyBlue' 'cyan' 'lightBlue' 'default';
@themes-light: 'grey' 'lightBlue';
@themes-dark: 'green' 'yellow' 'red' 'brown' 'darkBlue' 'navyBlue' 'cyan' 'default';
@theme-count: length(@themes);

.createThemes(@theme-count);

.createThemes(@n, @i: 1) when (@i =< @n) {
@theme : extract(@themes,@i) ;
  .dashboard-@{theme} {
    background-color: ~'@{theme-@{theme}}' ;
    color: ~'@{theme-@{theme}-text}';
  }
  .createThemes(@n, (@i + 1));
}
```

And here's the output:

```
.dashboard-'green' {
  background-color: #91ab7a;
  color: #fff;
}
.dashboard-'yellow' {
  background-color: #efdf91;
  color: #00395d;
}
.dashboard-'red' {
  background-color: #722d3d;
  color: #fff;
}
.dashboard-'brown' {
  background-color: #a9a196;
  color: #fff;
}
.dashboard-'grey' {
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
  color: #00395d;
}
.dashboard-'darkBlue' {
  background-color: #00395d;
  color: #fff;
}
.dashboard-'navyBlue' {
  background-color: #007db5;
  color: #fff;
}
.dashboard-'cyan' {
  background-color: #00adee;
  color: #fff;
}
.dashboard-'lightBlue' {
  background-color: #b1e7ff;
  color: #00395d;
}
.dashboard-'default' {
  background-color: #00395d;
  color: #fff;
}
```

This is very nearly what I want, but for the fact that the theme name is quoted in the generated selector, eg instead of `dashboard-'navyBlue'` I should see `dashboard-navyBlue`. How can I adjust the mixin to remove these quotes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a little bit of tinkering, I was able to find the following working solution:

```
@theme-green: #91ab7a;
@theme-green-text: #fff;
@theme-yellow: #efdf91;
@theme-yellow-text: #00395d;
@theme-red: #722d3d;
@theme-red-text: #fff;
@theme-brown: #a9a196;
@theme-brown-text: #fff;
@theme-grey: #f3f3f3;
@theme-grey-text: #00395d;
@theme-darkBlue: #00395d;
@theme-darkBlue-text: #fff;
@theme-default: @theme-darkBlue;
@theme-default-text: @theme-darkBlue-text;
@theme-navyBlue: #007db5;
@theme-navyBlue-text: #fff;
@theme-cyan: #00adee;
@theme-cyan-text: #fff;
@theme-lightBlue: #b1e7ff;
@theme-lightBlue-text: #00395d;
@themes: 'green' 'yellow' 'red' 'brown' 'grey' 'darkBlue' 'navyBlue' 'cyan' 'lightBlue' 'default';
@themes-light: 'grey' 'lightBlue';
@themes-dark: 'green' 'yellow' 'red' 'brown' 'darkBlue' 'navyBlue' 'cyan' 'default';
@theme-count: length(@themes);

.createThemes(@theme-count);

.createThemes(@n, @i: 1) when (@i =< @n) {
@theme : extract(@themes,@i) ;
@selector: ~'dashboard-@{theme}';
  @{selector} {
    background-color: ~'@{theme-@{theme}}' ;
    color: ~'@{theme-@{theme}-text}';
  }
  .createThemes(@n, (@i + 1));
}
```